# Express body parser not parsing object correctly

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

When I use

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
```

And the client posted this:

```
form:
{
    permission: {'45': 'asdf'},
    project_id: '98293949-c650-46d9-8bdb-fc57fb30fd88',
    task_id: '86325d50-7813-40ae-a8f9-7ddaf3f1790d',
    user_id: 'uvjKMSB0euYrCy45XhmpuQEQaZF2'
}
```

And When I console.log the req.body

```
res.send('the api is working'+JSON.stringify(req.body),);
```

> {"permission":["asdf"],"project_id":"98293949-c650-46d9-8bdb-fc57fb30fd88","task_id":"86325d50-7813-40ae-a8f9-7ddaf3f1790d","user_id":"uvjKMSB0euYrCy45XhmpuQEQaZF2"}

Why the body request at the field permission is **"permission":["asdf"]** instead of **{'45': 'asdf'}** ?

Comment: What's the `content-type` sent by the client? Is it `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` ?

Comment: The reason is within the code, look anywhere for 'permission' and you'll probably find a middleware that modifies it.